# Determinant functions

Tags: matrices, determinant

Given the alternating and $n$-multilinear transformation $f:(K^n)^n \to K^m$.

Show that $$ f_1,\cdots,f_m: (K^n)^n \to K$$
are determinant functions, where $f_i$ is defined as
$$ f_i := \pi_i \circ f$$
where $\pi_i$ is also defined as 
$$ \pi_i : K^m \to K, \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1 \\ \cdots \\ \alpha_m \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \alpha_i, \forall i \in (1,\cdots,m)$$
I could really use some tips here.

Comment: **Hint:** Can you exhibit a basis of alternating $n$-multilinear forms $(K^n)^n\to K$?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question, I couldn't understand it.  Sorry

Comment: Ok. Show that such an alternating $f:(K^n)^n\to K$ is uniquely determined by the value $f(e_1,e_2,\dots, e_n)$ where $(e_i)$ is the standard basis.

Comment: I could do that but how does that relate to my question ?

Comment: Then conclude, e.g. using Gauss elimination, that $f(a_1,\dots, a_n) =\lambda\det(a_1,\dots, a_n)$ for all vectors $a_i$, where $\lambda =f(e_1,\dots, e_n)$.

Comment: I'm really struggling with this.
Could you please give more tips.

Comment: Using elementary operations, starting out from the basis $e_i$ (e.g. $a_i':=a_i+\lambda a_j$) we can arrive to arbitrary list of $n$ vectors. Show that the determinant is changing exactly as $f$ for the elementary operations.

Comment: Could you please recommend a video/video series/article that has all of the underlying concepts needed to understand the question and your answer. I think I'm missing some important information about this topic.

Comment: Just google 'determinant by elimination' or 'row/column reduction', it's the same.